# How can I (efficiently) match content (lines) of many small files with content (lines) of a single large file and update/recreate them

Tags: powershell

I've tried solving the following case:

many small text files (in subfolders) need their content (lines) matched to lines that exist in another (large) text file. The small files then need to be updated or copied with those matching Lines.

I was able to come up with some running code for this but I need to improve it or use a complete other method because it is extremely slow and would take >40h to get through all files.

One idea I already had was to use a SQL Server to bulk-import all files in a single table with [relative path],[filename],[jap content] and the translation file in a table with [jap content],[eng content] and then join [jap content] and bulk-export the joined table as separate files using [relative path],[filename]. Unfortunately I got stuck right at the beginning due to formatting and encoding issues so I dropped it and started working on a PowerShell script.

Now in detail:

1. Over 40k txt files spread across multiple subfolders with multiple lines each, every line can exist in multiple files.

   ```
    Content:

    UTF8 encoded Japanese text that also can contain special characters like \\[*+(), each Line ending with a tabulator character. Sounds like csv files but they don't have headers.
   ```
2. One large File with >600k Lines containing the translation to the small files. Every line is unique within this file.

   ```
    Content:

    Again UTF8 encoded Japanese text. Each line formatted like this (without brackets):

    [Japanese Text][tabulator][English Text]

    Example:

    テスト[1]  Test [1]
   ```
3. End result should be a copy or a updated version of all these small files where their lines got replaced with the matching ones of the translation file while maintaining their relative path.

What I have at the moment:

```
$translationfile = 'B:\Translation.txt'
$inputpath = 'B:\Working'

$translationarray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$translationarray = @(Get-Content $translationfile -Encoding UTF8)

Get-Childitem -path $inputpath -Recurse -File -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    $_.Name
    $filepath = ($_.Directory.FullName).substring(2) 
    $filearray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $filearray = @(Get-Content -path $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8)
    $filearray = $filearray | ForEach-Object {
        $result = $using:translationarray -match ("^$_" -replace '[[+*?()\\.]','\$&')
        if ($result) {
            $_ = $result
        }
        $_
    }
    If(!(test-path B:\output\$filepath)) {New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path B:\output\$filepath}
    #$("B:\output\"+$filepath+"\")
    $filearray | Out-File -FilePath $("B:\output\" + $filepath + "\" + $_.Name) -Force -Encoding UTF8
} -ThrottleLimit 10
```

I would appreciate any help and ideas but please keep in mind that  I rarely write scripts so anything to complex might fly right over my head.

Thanks

Comment: You currently have to do m * n regex matches, which will be very slow. You should parse translation file only once to build a hashtable (japanese text as key and english text as value). Hashtable allows for much faster lookup than array (similar to indexed SQL table). Use `String.split()` instead of regex to further improve performance.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I read about this advantage of hash tables but struggled with the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) states, using a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) is your best option for mapping the Japanese-only phrases to the dual-language lines.

Additionally, use of .NET APIs for file I/O can speed up the operation noticeably.

```
# Be sure to specify all paths as full paths, not least because .NET's 
# current directory usually differs from PowerShell's
$translationfile = 'B:\Translation.txt'
$inPath = 'B:\Working'
$outPath = (New-Item -Type Directory -Force 'B:\Output').FullName

# Build the hashtable mapping the Japanese phrases to the full lines.
# Note that ReadLines() defaults to UTF-8
$ht = @{ }
foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines($translationfile)) {
  $ht[$line.Split("`t")[0] + "`t"] = $line
}

Get-ChildItem $inPath -Recurse -File -Filter *.txt | Foreach-Object -Parallel {
  # Translate the lines to the matching lines including the $translation
  # via the hashtable.
  # NOTE: If an input line isn't represented as a key in the hashtable,
  #       it is passed through as-is.
  $lines = foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadLines($_.FullName)) {
    ($using:ht)[$line] ?? $line
  }
  # Synthesize the output file path, ensuring that the target dir. exists.
  $outFilePath = (New-Item -Force -Type Directory ($using:outPath + $_.Directory.FullName.Substring(($using:inPath).Length))).FullName + '/' + $_.Name
  # Write to the output file.
  # Note: If you want UTF-8 files *with BOM*, use -Encoding utf8bom
  Set-Content -Encoding utf8 $outFilePath -Value $lines
} -ThrottleLimit 10
```

Note: Your use of `ForEach-Object -Parallel` implies that you're using *PowerShell [Core] 7+*, where BOM-less UTF-8 is the consistent default encoding (unlike in *Window PowerShell*, where default encodings vary wildly).

Therefore, in lieu of the .NET `[IO.File]::ReadLines()` API in a `foreach` loop, you could also use the more PowerShell-idiomatic [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with the `-File` parameter for efficient line-by-line text-file processing.